# Sort-of-multiplicative functions on the group algebra

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.  Which functions $f:G \to \mathbf{C}$ obey the equation
$$
\sum_{g \in C_1,h \in C_2} f(gh) = \left(\sum_{g \in C_1} f(g) \right)\left(\sum_{h \in C_2} f(h)\right)
$$
for all conjugacy classes $C_1,C_2 \subset G$?  Can you determine all such functions from the character table of $G$?